# Android - Remove views in a layout recursively

Tags: android

Is there a way to remove the views from a layout recursively? The function *removeAllViewsInLayout()* does not seem to do the task (it removes all views from a layout, but not the layout's children views). In my program, I add some FrameLayouts dynamically over a RelativeLayout, and over these FrameLayouts I add some ImageViews and TextViews. So I want to know if I'll have to go make my own recursive removing-view-code or if there is some available.

Comment: Did you try just removing the FrameLayouts instead of the TextViews/ImageViews and then rolling back to the FrameLayout?

Comment: If I go through each View the way you say, it works (and that's what I'm doing). So I just wanted to know if the is a function that does the job for me or if I have to do it by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can consider the layout as a tree. Thus, you only need a reference to the root node. If you remove it, it will be collected along with its children, since nothing else references them.

If for some reason you still see some Views after this operation, it means they belonged to a different node. You can always use the Hierarchy Viewer to "see" your UI better: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html

Comment: I thought that would work but I was unsure whether to remove the root or to go through each View and remove them. Maybe there were some trick with one way or another. But since there seems not to be, yours is the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a recursive example, but I believe that it can solve your problem:

```
public void ClearRelLayout(RelativeLayout RL){
    for(int x=0;x<RL.getChildCount();x++){
        if(RL.getChildAt(x) instanceof FrameLayout){
            FrameLayout FL = (FrameLayout) RL.getChildAt(x);
            FL.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        }
    }
    RL.removeAllViewsInLayout();
}
```

Rather than using recursion, just loop through each child and clear it if it is a `FrameLayout`

Comment: Shouldn't it call `removeAllViews()` instead of `removeAllViewsInLayout()` JavaDoc from the latter "Do not call this method unless you are extending ViewGroup and understand the view measuring and layout pipeline."

Comment: I think you can do one better and instead of checking `instanceof FrameLayout`, you can check `instanceof ViewGroup`. You'll catch the other layouts (`LinearLayout`, `GridLayout`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

First, normally you should call `removeAllViews()` instead of `removeAllViewsInLayout()` read the JavaDoc for the difference.

Also neither of these functions are recursive, they only remove the views from the object it is called on. Sub-structures will not change. This might cause problems and even memory leaks, if they have references to other objects that are kept.

For example if you have the following structure:

```
    <LinearLayout id='top'>
      <LinearLayout id='sub'>
        <Button id='b'/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and call `removeAllViews()` on `top` the layout `sub` will still refer `b` (and `b` will refer `sub` as parent). This means that you cannot reuse `b` somewhere else without first removing it parent (`sub`). If you do you will get an Exception.

Comment: But will the layout `sub` and all it's children be garbage collected? I've been trying to find the answer to this and I'm hoping it's yes since nothing else will be referencing `sub`.

Comment: It should since they have no external references, but I don't know that (a badly written gc could leave them, or maybe there is some other hidden reference by Android)